# How can I embed interactive transcript in my site?

Tags: flash, interactive, transcription

Is there a free or paid interactive transcript service I can embed in my site?
I found couple of services but I have to give them the video to transcript it and then they will give me the code to embed in my site, but what I want is to be able to host this service in my site with my transcription I made my self and even give it as free service to my clients.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of solution providers:

- Wistia: http://wistia.com/product/transcripts
- 3Play Media: http://www.3playmedia.com/interactive/
- ProTranscript: http://www.protranscript.com/
- Speakertext: http://speakertext.com/captionbox
- ClickableCaptions: http://clickablecaptions.com/captioning-with-instant-search/
- SubPly: http://www.subply.com/en/Products/InterActiveTranscript.htm

I just had to find some myself, so HTH.